# Position of android emulator with windows panel on the top of the screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have my windows panel on the top of the screen (usualy is on the bottom) and when I start the application, it starts behind that panel (like y.startPosition=0 and it should be =panelHeight) so I can not move with window and I do not see top of it. Any advice how to fix this please?

for a better understanding:
[screenshot of the problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16646198/droid.png)

Answer (score 0):

@zzemion I haven't found a "fix" for this but I do have a work around. Whenever you're coding, just set the taskbar to "auto hide" so that you can move the window whenever you need to. Not a great work around, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. When emulator will start, you need to start the same one again, so you will have two running, but second one should pop up normally and you can move with it. After this, you can close the first one and then it will work for your next time too.